# How to lock ViewPager to allow only a single page swipe at once

Tags: android, android-viewpager

By default, when you swipe over a ViewPager, you can swipe over as many pages as you can until your finger reaches the end of the screen. So, is it possible to force the ViewPager to only allow one page change no matter how much the user swipes?

This is what I mean by swiping over pager until your finger reaches the end of the screen:
[image: what I have]

And this is what I mean by locking the ViewPager to allow only a single page swipe at a time:
[image: this is what I want to achieve]

Thanks.

Comment: I think I'm not understanding your question properly, since a single swipe gesture only moves to the next or previous `fragment` (or page, if you want). Could you reformulate it?

Comment: You'd probably have to write a chunk of code to do that, but I would be more concerned about the user experience.  It would be confusing if the user swipes and sometimes the page scrolls, sometimes it doesn't.  You might consider a different view where you have a left and right button, and the user moves the pages by using the buttons, not by scrolling.

Comment: However, if you absolutely had to do this, probably the easiest way would be to modify the Adapter for your ViewPager so that it only gives three pages: the one displayed, the one to the left, and the one to the right.  Then when the user selects the next page, update the adapter by making the next page the current page, and return a three-page set again, only moved over one page.

Comment: The problem which you are specifying here doesn't happen with view pager. It happens in case of gallery.

Comment: I've added gif images to provide a detailed explanation of what I'm talking about.

Comment: @krislarson Yeah, I though about doing it in the adapter. But it'd be great if I could manage to get the ViewPager do it directly.

Comment: I'm developing an app right now that uses ViewPager. interestingly, I don't have that behavior.  And I think the reason why is because the ViewPager is inside *another* ViewPager, which is probably grabbing the swipe gesture. In other words, where your ViewPager "captures" the drag outside of the ViewPager container, my ViewPager is next to something that chews up swipe events so that the ViewPager doesn't scroll.  Which leads me to believe the answer lies somewhere with overriding onTouchEvent(), or onInterceptTouchEvent(), or calling requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(). Will investigate.

Comment: So your goal is: You want to have ViewPager stop capturing swipe events that are outside of the ViewPager container so that the user can never scroll by more than one page during a single swipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I ended up doing it in the adapter. What I did was returning `2` in the `getCount` method, rearranging items after a selection, and specially handling cases when an item from the dataset was to be accessed using the current position (0 or 1).

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think the answer is: Extend `ViewPager` and override `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)`.

```
private Rect viewRect = new Rect();

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    getHitRect(viewRect);

    if (viewRect.contains(
        Math.round(view.getX() + event.getX()),
        Math.round(view.getY() + event.getY()))) {

        // touch is inside, do normal behavior
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    } else {
        // touch is outside, consume the event & do nothing
        return true;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, don't have time to really test it out right now, I'll update later.

Comment: This doesn't really work as desired. If you start swiping, say, from the center, the movement will stop once you move your finger outside the pager.

Comment: I was thinking that I could do something with the onTouchEvent, just didn't know what. This answer gave me an idea. I'll see if it'll work once I get home.